# Manipulate GeoJSON Data - reload vector Layer in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I’m stuck on creating a function that manipulates loaded GeoJSON data and updates the OpenLayers Map. What I have so far is a map that works with data filtered from a loaded GeoJSON file. How do I change the vector layer to use updated data?

That’s my code so far:

- load GeoJSON `fullGeoJSON`:

  ```
  var fullGeoJSON = require("./data/data.json");
  ```
- create var filteredGeoJSON

  ```
  var filteredGeoJSON = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": []
  };
  ```
- fill empty `features` by filtering the `fullGeoJSON`

  ```
  function filterGeoJSON(religion, gender) {
      fullGeoJSON.features.forEach(function (feature) {
          if (
              feature.properties.religion == religion &&
              feature.properties.gender == gender
          ) {
              filteredGeoJSON.features.push(feature);
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- define a vector source

  ```
  var filteredSource = new VectorSource({
      features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(filteredGeoJSON, {
          featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
      })
  });
  ```
- define new vector layer using the source

  ```
  var filteredLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: filteredSource
  });
  ```

define map (`mainMap`) using the vector source. The Map renders fine with only the
    features shown that are left over after filtering the input JSON

Now I’m looking for a way to change the `filteredGeoJSON` by the click of a button by calling filterGeoJSON() with different parameters and use this changed data source for refreshing the `filteredSource` and hence the `filteredLayer`. What I have so far is:

```
onClick("gender", function () {
    // clear filteredGeoJSON
    (filteredGeoJSON = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: []
    });
    filterGeoJSON("protestantisch", "f"); // call filterGeoJSON again
    mainMap.refresh(); // <- Something like this?
});
```

How do I force OpenLayers to use the changed `filteredGeoJSON` from the onClick function as the datasource for my `mainMap`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the layer´s source to refresh the map´s content:

```
onClick("gender", function() {
   // clear filteredGeoJSON
   filteredGeoJSON = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: []
   };
   filteredSource = new VectorSource({
      features: filterGeoJSON("protestantisch", "f")
   })
  filteredLayer.setSource(filteredSource);
})
```

See [here.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html#setSource)

Comment: Thanks, it’s not very well documented but `setSource` works!